# Fighting an ideology takes decades

Tags: phrase-meaning

> GOP Rep. Waltz: Fighting an ideology takes decades
> Rep. Michael Waltz, R-Fla., was a special forces officer who served in Afghanistan. He also worked as an adviser to former Defense Secretaries Donald Rumsfeld and Robert Gates and as a counterterrorism adviser to then-Vice President Dick Cheney.

Source: USAToday   [What went wrong in Afghanistan? Perspectives on the 'forever war' from those who saw it up close](https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/politics/2021/08/18/us-afghanistan-failure-5-perspectives-those-who-saw/5505134001/)

Does "Fighting an ideology" mean "Fighting for an ideology"? Or "Fighting against an ideology"? If it were "Fighting an enemy", it means "fighting against an enemy", sure. But "Fighting an ideology"? For it or against it? I am not sure. Dictionaries define "fight" as "struggle vigorously for or against something" - okay, it doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are fighting X, you are opposed to X, and you want to see it stopped, removed, destroyed, etc. **Ideology** is no different than any other noun here, so if you are **fighting an ideology** you are naturally fighting against it. The usage here echoes **fighting a fever**, where you never fight **for** the fever; I have also heard **I fight my weight** -- another situation where you never fight **for** the weight.